# Как удалить последний пробел?

Tags: python

Допустим надо создать матрицу из чисел
Ввод:

```
2
23 34 
24 45
```

Нужен такой вывод  (_) - прост для наглядности

```
23_34
24_45
```

Получается такой

```
23_34_
24_45_
```

нужно убрать вот эти последние пробелы

```
N = int(input())
A = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(N)]
suma = 0
NM = []
for i in range(N):
  for j in range(N):
    NM.append(A[i][j])
    suma += A[i][j]
    LNM = len(NM)
    x = suma//LNM
for i in range(N):
  for j in range(N):
    if A[i][j] < x:
      A[i][j] = 0
    else:
      A[i][j] = 255
for i in range(len(A)):
  for j in range(len(A[i])):
    print(A[i][j], end = '')
  print()
```

Comment: Ваша программа и описанные вами вводы/выводы никак не соотносятся. Уточните этот момент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, смотреть на индекс и добавлять пробел перед элементами после первого:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
  for j in range(len(A[i])):
    if j > 0:
      print(end=' ')
    print(A[i][j], end='')
  print()
```

Или сгенерировать строку нужного формата (со всеми элементами, разделяя их пробелами через метод `join`):

```
for i in range(len(A)):
  print(' '.join(str(A[i][j]) for j in range(len(A[i]))))
```

Comment: Большое тебе спасибо прям выручил

Comment: @Venom, пожалуйста :) Отметьте мой ответ, пожалуйста, как решенный :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вывод делать через f-строку убрав пробелы вообще из вывода используя .strip() например

```
print(f"{'первый элемент'}_{'второй элемент'}") # _ для наглядности
```